# Selenium IDE with chosen select elements

Tags: testing, selenium-ide, jquery-chosen

I'm trying to test a registration form with Selenium IDE, but am having trouble with select elements from the Chosen library:
http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

I wonder if you can help me with the commands to select an option (could be any option by the way). I couldn't get past opening the dropdown with a simple mouseDown. Here's a sample webpage with both a single and multi select (download source files from the repository above.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chosen/public/chosen.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="chosen/public/chosen.jquery.min.css">
    <script src="jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="chosen/public/chosen.jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <select multiple class="chzn-select" style="width: 150px;">
        <option value="Test 1">Test 1</option>
        <option value="Test 2">Test 2</option>
        <option value="Test 3">Test 3</option>
    </select>
    <br><br>
    <select class="chzn-select" style="width: 150px;">
        <option value="Test A">Test A</option>
        <option value="Test B">Test B</option>
        <option value="Test C">Test C</option>
    </select>   

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".chzn-select").chosen();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok I did manage to crack it myself and it was as simple as:

> **Command**: clickAt
>
> **Target**: css=#id_country_chzn_o_1

(chooses the first item on a list of countries, use Firebug to find out what your ids are called)

Comment: That's great! I wonder why ClickAt works but Click doesn't. Even though ClickAt is called without coordinates.

Comment: What was your chosen select id and what were the values?

Comment: Just to add an additional hack I needed.. First I needed to add a: clickAt|id={my_select}_chosen  then I could do a clickAt on the specific option with: clickAt|//li[@data-option-array-index='1']

Answer (score 2):

Following steps solves this issue:
Step 01.

```
Command: clickAt
Target: id=iNationality_chosen
```

Step 02.

```
Command: clickAt
Target: css=div[id='iNationality_chosen'] div ul li:nth-child(2)
```

Note 01: **iNationality**_chosen here you can replace the id with your element ID

Note 02: li:nth-child(**2**) here you can provide any number that you a wish to select. 2 will be selecting the second child (option list).

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem before. The solution is pretty simple and normal. This is the best practice for Select command in Selenium IDE. Here it is:

1. **Command** : Choose **select** as your Command
2. **Target** : Select your element ID you want to point at
3. **Value** : Set your value using this format **index=1**  // this is the most important thing, and then you can change the number to your prefered number

For example:

1. **Command**: select
2. **Target**: id=province
3. **Value**: index=2

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using selenium api and robotframework. The element wasn't clickable because chosen adds a `display:none`. I solved it by executing a jquery javascript which removes the style attribute.

In robotframework style:

> Execute Javascript    $("#id").removeAttr("style");

Where id is the id of the select.